# GatsbyJS webpack error, undefined variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, webpack, gatsby

I have huge difficulty understanding the error that the server throws out when I run gatsby build to build the public files on my nginx server

```
error Building static HTML for pages failed
WebpackError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

The weird thing is that when I run gatsby develop, build on my local machine, everything works fine, no error is given. Only when I run gatsby build on my Nginx server, does this error pop out. Both the files are synced correctly as well.

According to the error, tags is not defined. But it does exist, I have checked using localhost graphQL. Which then goes to the way I'm describing the variables but if it is not working then the rest like title, slug, date, html should not work as well. But it does when I take out the tags.

```
    const {title, date, slug, excerpt } = this.props.data.contentfulBlog;
    const tags = this.props.data.contentfulBlog.category;
    const html = this.props.data.contentfulBlog.childContentfulBlogHtmlTextNode.childMarkdownRemark.html;

    return(
    <div>
      <Helmet> 
            <title>{title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={excerpt}/>
            <meta name="keywords" content={tags.map((tag) => (String(tag.tagTitle)))}/>
      </Helmet>
```

So I have no idea why I can't access the tags variable when building it on my server but it works on the local machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why you need to use the meta `keywords` since Google and other search engines [don't use it for their ranking system](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html), I think you can solve your issue by doing something like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content={tags ? tags.map((tag) => (String(tag.tagTitle))) : ''}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

In my case, the prop `x` is an array and is required. but calling `x.map` returns

```
cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I fixed it by giving prop `x` a default value `[]`.